# How to hollow a filled curve?

Tags: bezier-curves

I have the following curve (imported from an svg object):

[image]

and I want to extract the borders of it and ignore the faces.
I've tried converting it to `mesh` and deleting the faces in edit mode but that would delete the whole object.
Is it possible to hollow that object ? (It's possible to draw some beziers and match it to current curve's borders , but it seems too time-consuming for a complicated object).

Thanks.

Comment: Hi, when you convert to mesh and then X > delete only faces, the edges should remain.

Comment: @Fowl Hi. OK. Works.But that leaves the vertices unconnected .How can I re-connect them without filling the object again?

Comment: You clicked on the only edges and faces or only faces? When I convert tis shape to mesh select all and then delete only faces, you get verteces and eges left.

2) just select the border and duplicate

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Convert object to mesh > edit mode-edges > ALT + double click on the border to select all > shift+D to duplicate > P-separate by selection. You have the border without insides.
[image]

Comment: Important : Selection mode should be set to "Edge select" in edit mode.

Answer (score 3):

You can change fill mode of the curve object. In curve properties go to Shape and change Fill Mode to None.

[image: screenshot of the settings]

Comment: After this, you may also need to change the *Mean Radius* to zero, in the *Transform* menu.